# Extend Object Type and Overwrite Property in Flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype, flow-typed

In TypeScript, I am able to do the following:

```
interface MyObj {
    a: 'foo' | 'bar'
}

interface MyExtObj extends Pick<MyObj, Exclude<keyof MyObj, 'a'>> {
    a: MyObj['a'] | 'baz'
}

const test: MyExtObj = {
    a: 'baz' // Works fine, as well as 'foo' and 'bar'
}
```

Is it possible to do that with Flow object types and if so, how? The following example fails...

```
/* @flow */

type MyObj = {
    a: 'foo' | 'bar'
}

type MyExtObj = MyObj & {
    a: $PropertyType<MyObj, 'a'> | 'baz'
}

const test: MyExtObj = {
    a: 'baz' // Cannot assign object literal blah blah ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
/* @flow */

type MyObj = {|
    a: 'foo' | 'bar'
|}

type MyExtObj = {|
    ...MyObj,
    a: $PropertyType<MyObj, 'a'> | 'baz'
|}

const test: MyExtObj = {
    a: 'baz' // Cannot assign object literal blah blah ...
}
```

You can test [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyWA8gEYBWYAvGAN4A+qYLYAhgFxgDkUcc3MAx5k2AJ26oGAX3TZ8RLAFEAHhnJVajZmACQAOkPENAGh0tOYACQAFMXHxjsAFVx4APMcomebbgD4hETYAL0kZdABjOAA7AGcMMAw8BK5iVXVKGnpzdi5uUTCwYGAwAGE2GJi4RLY4uIBLAHMYsDhKPEjEmAbksTYYMDIYNgALIZHxw31UaSA)

Answer (score 1):

This [also works](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyWA8gEYBWYAvGAN6phNgCGAXGAORRxydgAfLmRYAnTqgC+6bPiJYAogA8M5KrToDGYAJAA6AwBJlLAMYYAPMTUA+ADTam7MIYAKouPlHYAKrjxWpJR2XCycNoLCLABeEgLSqKZwAHYAzhhgGHjpHMTKqpQ09I6sHJwisWDAwGAAwizJyXAZLKmpAJYA5slgcJR45mAw7VmiLDBgZDAsABaT03MGelJAA), in case you don't want to make MyObj exact for some reason:

```
/* @flow */

type MyObj = {
    a: 'foo' | 'bar'
}

type MyExtObj = {|
    ...$Exact<MyObj>,
    a: $PropertyType<MyObj, 'a'> | 'baz'
|}

const test: MyExtObj = {
    a: 'baz' // Cannot assign object literal blah blah ...
}
```